# Two viewControllers, but 1 viewController Scene in Storyboard

Tags: xcode, view, storyboard, viewcontroller

A little background. i have two viewControllers each with their own objects, but i would like to put them into one viewController Scene.

In my ViewController2, there is an IBOutlet UIImageView *drawImage which is supposed to be connected to a UIImageView in the one viewController Scene which is ViewController1's view controller scene.

In the only view controller scene, this UIImageView is embeded on a View(lets call it View2) which belongs to the ViewController2 and in that controller is all the code responsible for recognising the finger strokes.

This View2 that i previously mentioned is sitting in another bigger View(lets call this View1). So it is like View2 in View1(main).

View1 = ViewController1 and the second smaller View2 = ViewController2.

Two different ViewControllers(.h & .m), 1 View Controller Scene in storyboard.

Any idea how i can achieve it?

Comment: How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312275/how-can-i-store-button-presses-into-a-different-xib-and-view-them/9322801#9322801) will work for you. A container view is used to load your two different views. You can put the code in a method which is called when you recognize gestures or button presses or whatever.

Comment: I think your answer talks about **transitioning between** two views but the question is about displaying two **views at the same time**.